# Android Layout with variable fragment size

Tags: android, layout

I have an android app I'm building that has a static sized top fragment, and a chat box below.

The chat box has an input that's the footer of the screen. When the keyboard pops up, the input comes up with it, obscuring the bottom section of the chat display. How do I anchor my chat display to the bottom of my top fragment, and to the top of my input fragment (sandwiching it between them) with adjusting total height?